# Why the Enumerator of List<T> is public?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the reason for the public access modifier on the Enumerator in List?

I would expect private modifier instead of public.

[List source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1140)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be public?

Comment: well, Inheritance? i mean `List<T>` implements `IList<T>` which implements `ICollection<T>` which implements `IEnumerable<T>`which exposes `GetEnumerator()`

Comment: @PatrickHofman because in the absence of reasons to make it public it is better to make it private and because it is an implementation detail. Had it been private the implementation could change without problems. Therefore if the designers sacrificed this option they must have had a good reason to do so. I think the question is quite reasonable.

Comment: I just meant OP assumed it was a bad thing, and I questioned that. @Stilgar

Comment: Well it is not a bad thing it is just not the default thing so there must have been a reason.

BTW why are people voting to close this question? It is not opinion based. As Jon Skeet's answer clearly explains there is a very precise technical reason why the decision was made.

Comment: People who have closed the question as opinion based go read the answer and tell me how a clear performance consideration is opinion based!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's public so that the `GetEnumerator()` method can be *declared* to return it.

That then allows the C# compiler to use it in a `foreach` loop... avoiding any heap allocations **because `List.Enumerator` is a struct**. (A mutable struct, which makes me go "urgh!" but that's another story.)

So when you have something like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "..." };
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Then the compiler can convert it into something like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "..." };
using (List<string>.Enumerator enumerator = list.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        string item = enumerator.Current;
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Note the type of `enumerator` here - whereas if we had:

```
IEnumerable<string> list = new List<string> { "..." };
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

it would use:

```
using (IEnumerator<string> enumerator = list.GetEnumerator())
```

... which involves a heap allocation as `IEnumerator<string>` is a reference type. The `IEnumerable<T>` implementation of `GetEnumerator()` in `List<T>` returns a *boxed* `List<string>.Enumerator`.

Comment: What do you mean by "avoiding any heap allocations"?

Comment: @TamasIonut: See my expanded answer.

Comment: You forgot to specify that the point is that `Enumerator` is a `struct` not a `class`. For this reason the `GetEnumerator()` is *avoiding any heap allocations*

Answer (score 1):

Simply because it is reused in a lot of [other assemblies](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,9c3d580a8b7a8fe8,references).

You can discuss whether that is a valid reason to use the struct and not the underlying interface, but that is the foremost reason I guess.